# I am getting error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I am getting the error

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException:
Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open(Boolean silent)
at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeConnection.Open()
```

`1.db3` is that database and its size is around 3.8 GB.

Does the size of db can lead such error ? Please explain the possible reason for such error.

```
 private void TestConnection()
    {
        if (_connection != null && _connection.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _connection.Close();
            _connection.Dispose();
        }
        _connection = new SqlCeConnection(_connectionString);
        _connection.Open();
    }

private string  _connectionString = "C:\1.db3;password='apple';mode=Read Write;max database size=4091;temp file max size=4091";
private SqlCeConnection _connection;
```

Comment: just wondering...your `max database size=4091` is in the connection string....

Comment: @jjchiw - some things must be asked for the humorous side methinks :)

Comment: It is an out of memory resources error, what platform are you running?

Comment: It work well for other database file (.db3) but gives problem only on that database file.